# How can i generate the sha256 hash for content_security_policy in a react web extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, content-security-policy, sha256

I am building a web extension with React.

In my manifest I have `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-IzNmFGqxklSslwrOnjdh7kh6FQtwaX9xFT47WF'; object-src 'self'"`.

As the script changes I need to update the manifest with an updated sha256 hash. I am currently using the chrome dev tools to get the hash. It will yell at me that I need one, and show me the hash.

How can I generate this on the go for a React App, instead of using the chrome dev tools?

Comment: Several pages claim that you can get the sha256 part if you pipe all characters between the script tags (excluding them) to `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary|openssl base64`  but that seems to generate the wrong hash